# Hibernate does not validate entity with UUID primary key on persist via Junit test

Tags: hibernate, junit, hibernate-validator, spring-test

I have an entity with UUID primary key

```
@Id
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
@Column(name = "gid")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private UUID id;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "full_name")
private String fullName;
```

When I save an object with null or empty fullName via Jpa repository in debug mode all is OK. But I have a Junit-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringWebApplicationTestCase
public class OrganizationTest extends AbstractTestConfig {

@Autowired
OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

private Organization organization;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    organization = new Organization();
}

@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void createOrganizationValidation() throws Exception {
    organizationRepository.save(organization);
}
}
```

It fails because validation not fired. I found that there is a method "execute" in EntityInsertAction which not fired.

hibernate-validator 5.2.1 Final
hibernate 4.3.10 Final

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `organizationRepository.flush` after the save operation. Bean Validation kicks in prior to writing to the database.